# How to fix, does not wait for a respons, but begin to render

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

```
 areasGet = async(Index) => {
    let res = await fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/areas/113`)
    let json = await res.json()
    this.setState({
      areaData: json,
      isLoadArea: true
    })
     // console.log(json)
  }


  specGet = async(Index) => {
    let res = await fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/specializations`)
    let json = await res.json()
    this.setState({
      specData: json,
      isLoadSpec: true
    })
  }

  industriesGet = async(Index) => {
    let res = await fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/industries`)
    let json = await res.json()
    this.setState({
      industriesData: json,
      isLoadInd: true
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.areasGet()
    this.specGet()
    this.industriesGet()
  }
```

When performing, then one is not filled, then another, randomly in general. Like synchrony, but why the error..

The render () itself works only if all 3 isLoad are true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait to all of them, and mark to the render that it can render, so, you can introduce a `state` property, let's call it, `isLoaded`.

It's value should start with `false`, and become `true` only when the 3 ajax requests are done.

You have 2 choices to do so:

1. async-await syntax
2. Promise.all

Example:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Promise.all([this.areasGet(), this.specGet(), this.industriesGet()]);
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;

    if (isLoaded) {
      return <div>Here is you component that needs all the 3 ajax requests</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: async-await don't help me(
The render started when all 3 isLoad were true. In spite of this, he wrote down empty arrays in data, which is why .map swore

Comment: Not sure I've got the issue, the render will render loading till all the data will finish the async operation.